# Getting null pointer in hibernate dao when calling from jsp

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, nullpointerexception

Here is my code in jsp,

```
   <%
        JSonHandler jSonHandler = new JSonHandler();
        jSonHandler.setList(jSonHandler.getHolidayDetails());
        JSONArray obj = jSonHandler.getJsonArray();
    %>
```

And from the JSonHandler  class ,I am calling a hibernateDAO method that returns an arraylist of object. But I've got a null pointer instead.

This is my JSonHandler class

```
public class JSonHandler 
{
    private LeaveAdminDAO leaveAdminDAO = new LeaveAdminHibernateDAO();
    private Map<String, String> map;
    private List<Map<String, String>> list;
    public List<Map<String, String>> getHolidayDetails()
    {
        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        List<Holidays> holidayDetails = leaveAdminDAO.getHolidayDetails(year);
        map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for(int i=0; i<holidayDetails.size(); i++)
        {
            map.put("title", holidayDetails.get(0).getHolidayDescription());
            map.put("start", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(holidayDetails.get(0).getHolidayDate()));
            list.add(map);
        }
        return list;
    }
    public List<Map<String, String>> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Map<String, String>> list) 
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public JSONArray getJsonArray()
    {
        JSONArray obj = JSONArray.fromObject(list);
        return obj;
    }
```

Someone help me thanks in advance.

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.experion.lts.util.JSonHandler.getHolidayDetails(JSonHandler.java:28)
    org.apache.jsp.views.markholidays_jsp._jspService(markholidays_jsp.java:72)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:653)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:647)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    org.apache.jsp.views.layout.MainLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(MainLayout_jsp.java:196)
    org.apache.jsp.views.layout.MainLayout_jsp._jspService(MainLayout_jsp.java:111)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.experion.lts.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:48)
```

DAO Code:

```
public List<Holidays> getHolidayDetails(int year)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Holidays> holidayDetails = getHibernateTemplate().find("from Holidays where holidayId = 1");
            return holidayDetails;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to put the stack trace?

Comment: Use debugger and paste stacktrace may help you.

Comment: Are you using an `OpenSessionInViewFilter`? This keeps the hibernate session open while rendering the JSP.

Comment: Is it the `holidayDetails` list that is `null`? Should it be returning data with the given parameter? If it does, post your DAO's relevant code, if it doesn't, just return an empty list from the DAO instead of `null`, or check for nullity once you receive it in your JSONHandler.

Comment: @Russell How could OSIV lead to an NPE in this situation?

Comment: The only way that I can see for getting a NullPointerException is if leaveAdminDAO.getHolidayDetails(year); returns null. Can you post the code of LeaveAdminHibernateDAO?.

Comment: @Xavi López ya I posted the code .

Comment: It seems like that `hibernateTemplate.find()` sentence is throwing an `Exception` of some kind. Either return `new ArrayList<Holidays>()` within the `catch` clause to swallow the exception, or propagate it by throwing a `RuntimeException`. It would also be good to know what's the exception like. Have you seen its stacktrace?

Comment: @Pablo I've tried it by calling from another service, it's working fine and i dont know what went wrong here

Comment: @TinoMThomas to find what went wrong, you need to find the stack trace that you print in "getHolidayDetails", see my answer. It should be in the console of the server or in some log file.

Comment: @XaviLópez Trying to use the session when it has been closed could be the cause of the exception that is being caught (meaning null is returned). You need to use an `OpenSessionInViewFilter` if you need to run Hibernate queries from within a JSP.

Comment: @XaviLópez I had no particular evidence to think it was that, just a hunch as I ran into similar problems when using Hibernate a while back, so I thought I would post it as a suggestion to look into.

Comment: @Russell Yeah, nice, you're right, just wanted to know :) It's just that I'm not used to doing hibernate queries from JSP's.

Comment: @XaviLópez Yes, there's probably a very good argument that it's bad practice... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an exception here:

```
    try
    {
        List<Holidays> holidayDetails = getHibernateTemplate().find("from Holidays where holidayId = 1");
        return holidayDetails;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

You catch the exception and return null, and then that null result causes a NullPointerException in your other class. You need to find the stack trace that you are printing (e.printStackTrace()) to know what's causing that exception.

Comment: It looks like quite a helpful answer to me! Have you tried what Pablo suggests?